# Create multiple windows with persistent context using playwright

Tags: playwright

I'm trying to launch multiple windows that are using the same user data dir.

When launching using [browserType.launchPersistentContext(userDataDir[, options])]](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-browsertype#browser-type-launch-persistent-context) and then using [browserContext.newPage()](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-browsercontext#browser-context-new-page) multiple times:

```
import playwright from 'playwright'

const browserContext = await playwright.chromium.launchPersistentContext('/tmp/profile', { headless: false })

await (await browserContext.newPage()).goto('https://example.com')
await (await browserContext.newPage()).goto('https://example.com')
await (await browserContext.newPage()).goto('https://example.com')
```

it will launch one window and then open one tab per page.

Unfortunately, [browserContext.browser()](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-browsercontext#browser-context-browser) specifically doesn't work for persistent contexts:

> Returns the browser instance of the context. If it was launched as a persistent context null gets returned.

so I cannot create multiple contexts.

How would I go with making it open multiple windows when using persistent contexts?

Answer (score 0):

I have debugged the communication between the Playwright package v1.24 and the Firefox browser. It seems to open multiple windows, all of them sharing a common browser context. As far as I can see, the only limitation is that you cannot open the pages in the same window.